# How to initialize class for XAML designer in VS 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have following markup extension defined in Utils.dll

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation", "Whatever")]
namespace Whatever
{
    public class GetString : MarkupExtension
    {
        public static ResourceManager ResourceManager { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }

        public GetString(string key)
        {
            Key = key;
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (ResourceManager == null) 
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            return ResourceManager.GetString(Key);
        }
    }
}
```

It allows me to write code like this: `<TextBlock Text="{GetString txt_login}" />`

Before I can use this class I have to initialize ResourceManager. I do it at application startup. Everything works fine except I can't use designer - it will always throw InvalidOperationException. Is there a way to initialize this class before designer tries to instantiate it?

Comment: So, basically, the designer is getting to `if (ResourceManager == null)` and because `ResourceManager` isn't initialized, the designer is throwing the exception on the next line..?

Comment: Yep. But goal here is not to swallow this exception in design mode but actually initialize ResourceManager to display correct strings.

Comment: Why can't `ResourceManager` be initialized within `GetString`?  (Where does it have to be initialized and why?)

Comment: There are 2 assemblies: 1. Utility assembly which contains `GetString` class and knows nothing about main assembly. 2. Main assembly that contains all the controls, and supplies its ResourceManager. It should initialize `GetString`

Comment: I'd suggest creating something similar to an attached property which you set in your App.xaml file.  (App.xaml is executed at design-time.) [This blog article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2011/02/09/blendability-part-iv-design-time-support-for-mef.aspx) shows a GREAT example of design-time code and would seem to be a great start for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add a property to this class, or in a static class somewhere as follows:

```
public bool IsDesignTime
{
    get
    {
       return (System.Windows.Application.Current == null) || (System.Windows.Application.Current.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Application));
    }
}
```

Then modify you Extension:

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    if (IsDesignTime)
    {
        // add code to init resource manager for design time
    }
    if (ResourceManager == null) 
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    return ResourceManager.GetString(Key);
}
```

The other option, is to just initialize the ResourceManager in this class if it's null.  Either works.